# How do I assign a User_ID to the seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to assign random user_id's to products that are generated from the seeds database. Everything is generating for me as I want it except for the user_id which is rendering nil. I'm trying to get a better understanding of how the belongs_to interaction works - any help here would be awesome!

```
10.times do |n|
 name = Faker::Name.name
 job = Faker::Company.name
 User.create!(name: name,
               job: job  )
end

10.times do |n|
 users = User.all
 name = "Turkey"
 price = Random.rand(42-10) + 10
 user_id = users[1..10] 
 Product.create!(name: name,
                 price: price,  
                 user_id: user_id)
end
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit ** Thanks for the help everyone. This is what I ended up changing the code to.

```
users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)
10.times do |n|
name = "Turkey"
price = Random.rand(42-10) + 10
users.each { |user| user.products.create!(name: name, price: price)}
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% what you're asking in terms of assigning a random user id to the product. From your comment on @tadman answer it seems you just want a product to belong to each one of the users. Why not just do something like this:

```
10.times do |n|
 name = Faker::Name.name
 job = Faker::Company.name
 User.create!(name: name, job: job)
end

User.all.each do |user|
 name = "Turkey"
 price = Random.rand(42-10) + 10
 user.products.create!(name: name, price: price)
end
```

Assuming your User model has many products and a product belongs to a User that should get your desired outcome.

`user.products` will automatically assign the `user.id` to the `user_id` field to the `product` record when sending `build` or `create`

Comment: Thanks, this sent me in the right direction. I edited my post with my change.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean this:

```
user_id = users.last.id
```

Or possibly:

```
user_id = users.shuffle.last.id
```

I'm not sure what your range notation `1..10` is intending. Arrays are 0-indexed.

Comment: Thanks Tadman. So User_id = Users.last.id works. How would I would approach getting Product 1 assigned to user 1, Product 2 assigned to user 2 etc...?

Answer (score 0):

User id will automatically get generated for each new user in sequential order. There is no need to have the "user_id" field there.

Comment: When I remove user_id out of the generation of the product it generates nil.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mukul215 said the ID will be generated automatically in sequential order. It is BAD practice to hard code ID's in the seed.

Comment: User_id is the foreign key. It doesn't seem to be generating anything for that field without that in there.